# Check amount of certain value in array that is stored in mongodb with nodejs

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, ejs

I have a question because I am trying to check if a certain value is avaible more then 1 times in a array that is stored in MongoDB. The render template i use is EJS, so the looping trough the array is currently working but now  I am trying to make it check the amount of the item "Bandage", but I have no idea how I could make that work. The function gets triggerd when you try to delete a certain item so it has to check how many you have of that specific item and then do something with it. The user_items is stored in the array that is stored in MongoDb and the <% %> + "" is for the EJS template and since its a bunch of strings they have to be written down with the "".

This is what I tried to do so far on the EJS page:

```js
<script>
const user_items = ["<%= user.items%>"]



//Checking if item(s) exist and delete them for the browser.


function  deleteitembandage(user_items){
const count = {}
const result = []

user_items.forEach(user_item => {
    if (count[user_item]) {
       count[user_item] +=1
       
     if ("Bandage" > 1) {
     alert('You have more then 2 Bandages')
}

       return
    }
    count[user_item] = 1
})

for (let prop in count){
    if (count[prop] >=2){
        result.push(prop)
    }
}

console.log(count)
return result;

}

deleteitembandage(user_items)


//Event listener delete button for bandage
document.getElementById('inventorydeletebandage').addEventListener('click', deleteitembandage)


</script>
```

However this will give me the error: Uncaught TypeError: user_items.forEach is not a function
at HTMLButtonElement.deleteitembandage (inventory:105).

What would be the way to do this?

Comment: When you invoke this function `document.getElementById('inventorydeletebandage').addEventListener('click', deleteitembandage)` by clicking delete, you are not passing the user_items parameter.

Comment: Okay so i try it like this: document.getElementById('inventorydeletebandage').addEventListener('click', deleteitembandage, user_items)    I still get results on the console.log but also still the error: Uncaught TypeError: user_items.forEach is not a function
    at HTMLButtonElement.deleteitembandage (inventory:105)

Comment: The third parameter of addEventListener is not for that purpose.  Either use `deleteitembandage.bind(null, user_items)` as the second parameter, or refactor your function to not accept a parameter at all and use the globally declared user_items.

Comment: Ah thanks okay that got rid of the error. But now to my other question, how could I check how many bandages are stored into that array?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use array.filter to create an array containing only "Bandage" items.  Then check the length of that array.  Make sure the string Bandage is exactly the same as what's in the array (upper/lower case wise).

```
const bandageCount = user_items.filter(item => item === "Bandage").length
```